# SUMIF equivalent in array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of value (say H6:H20) containing values "g","y" or "r".
In order to count each status and use that as the source of a donut chart, I made a range of 3 cells calculating `=COUNTIF($H$6:$H$20,"Green")` etc...

Then I tried to be more elegant and create a single **array formula returning the count for each letter**, that I could eventually use as the source of my chart, without having intermediry calculation range. But I can't get this working.

Input:

```
g
r
y
g
g
r
g
g
y
```

Expected output (with a **single array formula**):

```
5
2
2
```

My try: `=COUNTIF({"g","y","r"},$H$6:$H$20)`  -> error

Other try: `=SUMPRODUCT(1*$H$6:$H$20={"g","y","r"})`  -> error

(both entered in a 3 cells range with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, of course)

What is the right formula ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want `COUNTIFS()` instead perhaps? Do you want a single number, i.e. count all instances of "g", "y", and "r"? Or are you trying to return in a single cell the count of "g", then separately count of "y", then separately count of "r"?

Comment: @BruceWayne see edit in **bold**

Comment: Input with desired output would help us greatly.

Comment: @pnuts exactly that, but all 3 at once

Comment: `=INDEX(FREQUENCY(MATCH($H$6:$H$20,{"g","y","r"},0),MATCH($H$6:$H$20,{"g","y","r"},0)),ROWS($A$1:A1))` copy down.

Comment: Can you clarify how you want the solution? Your post looks like three rows, but you (in your reply to my answer), don't want that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an array formula, though you do need to store that formula as a Defined Name within Name Manager, e.g.:

*Name:* Series_Values

*Refers to:* `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$H$6:$H$20,{"g","y","r"})`

Change the sheet name (`Sheet1` here) as required.

You can then add a series to a chart with the following syntax for the *Series values* entry:

`='Sheet1'!Series_Values`

Again, amend the sheet name as required, though be sure to retain the exclamation mark and apostrophes (the latter are not strictly necessary if the worksheet name contains no spacing, though in any case it is good practice).

Excel will actually amend this to:

`=Book1!Series_Values`

(where `Book1` is the assumed workbook name), though this is not important here.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

That's what FREQUENCY function is for. Select 3 cells and CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER following formula:

`=FREQUENCY(MATCH($H$6:$H$20,{"g","y","r"},0),MATCH($H$6:$H$20,{"g","y","r"},0))`

Comment: Interesting. It returns 10, 0 ,0 where 10 is the right number of occurences of "g", the rest is not correct. I will try to understand this and explore. +1 anyway Thanks

Comment: @PatrickHonorez can you share the dataset? I will try it here and see.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this isn't dynamic, and you have a definite amount of rows, you can use the following.  Let's say you're putting this formula in row `20`:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,INDEX({"g","r","y"},ABS(20-(ROW()+1))))
```

and drag down.

Edit: If you want in the same cell, just combine `COUNTIF()`?

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,"g")&","&COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,"r")&","&COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,"y")
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I have to drag down, it's not a single array formula, and I won't be able to use itas the row source of a serie, which is my ultimate goal.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez You want the `5`, `2`, and `2` all in the same cell?  If so, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF({"g","y","r"}="g",COUNTIF($H$6:$H$20,"g"),IF({"g","y","r"}="y",COUNTIF($H$6:$H$20,"y"),IF({"g","y","r"}="r",COUNTIF($H$6:$H$20,"r"))))`

long solution as I don't have time to make a more elegant one. You can see the array object with F9 in the formula bar.